# Numbered arrows in latex

Tags: arrows

One of my programming books has a nice way to use "numbered arrows" to point to a specific line, or even portion of lines as in the enclosed photo.

Is there a package that would create such "numbered arrows" that points to texts *as well as* displayed equations, possibly spanning across multiple lines (like arrow 3 in the photo) and/or bended up or down?

I know that I can make an ad hoc hack using e.g. `TikZ`, but I was hoping for a more systematic way to do this via a `LaTeX` package.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `listings` package, with which it's possible to insert LaTeX command in the middle of verbatim code. There's also the `circledsteps` package to get ready-made numbers inside circles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{circledsteps}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, escapechar=|]
def f(x):  |$\leftarrow$\Circled{1}|
    y = x**2
    return y  |$\leftarrow$\Circled{2}|
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The use of `|` as an escape character is completely arbitrary, you can define something else depending on the characters that are needed for the specific language you're programming with.

You can use the same escape syntax to add labels to specific lines of code, which would be best if you want to refer to those lines later in the text.

[image: Numbered tags in listings]

Comment: Excellent!   Is there a version of this package for displayed math equations?  What about text paragraphs?  Also, is there a way for these arrows to line up?  THANKS!

Comment: Lining up the arrows is easy, since the code is verbatim, so it's rendered with a monospace font and spaces are *not* ignored. So adjust spaces before each arrow (outside the escaped parts) so that they line up. As for something similar for equations, it's a different question. If an answer doesn't already exists here, simply open a new question.